# Excel search a string and summarize the coherent cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excell. I like to find a special strings in a column and summarize their coherent cells. Short example:

```
1     C          D        E       F       G       H
2    name     ammount
3    coffee    130
4    sugar     200
5    coffee    120
6    coffee    120    total ammount of coffee:  370
```

In this example the total ammount of coffee is in cell H6. I didn't find an applicable built-in function. I think excel-vba would be better.

something like:

```
where = Range(C3:C6)
findx = 'coffee'
Dim ammount As Integer
 For Each row In where
  er = Application.Match(findx,0)
   If er == findx Then
      ammount = (ammount + (D[row]))
      Exit Sub
   End If
 H6 = ammount
End Sub
```

There are any syntax errors but I am a rookie in VBA. (yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need VBA, as there exists a built in function. Try `SUMIF`

`=SUMIF(C3:C6,"coffee",D3:D6)`